Would my reduction in these specific insect populations have a severe negative impact on Earth's ecosystem?
Setting is modern Earth. Earth has attracted the gaze of a cosmic horror. In around 5 years, the entity would fully descend on Earth.
One of the effects of his gaze is the sudden mass deaths of crickets, katydids, and cicadas globally. For each species of all three, there is a population reduction of 44%. The insects suddenly drop dead without any obvious cause. This effect is evenly spread out to the entire world.
I wanted this mass extermination to heavily impact the ecosystems where these insects engage in as entomologists notice this anomaly. Initially, I thought this would have severe impacts because of how important insects are to the ecology but after some research, it seems that the three insects' greatest ecological contribution is food(1, 2, 3) even if they also serve other purposes like pruning trees. The corpses would just get eaten or turned into fertilizer by nature. Even if the thousands of species of cicadas,  katydids, and crickets were to each get depopulated by nearly half, I assume their fertility rates would recover from this loss.
Have I underestimated these insects' involvement? Would this level of insect extermination truly irreversibly collapse ecosystems?

A little late. Late because many insect populations have fallen significantly since say 30 years ago. What do i mean?, A long summer drive in North America in the 80's and prior would leave a vehicle grill coated with insect corpses. Nowadays you don't really see that.  Impact of loss of insects: unknown.

World history is littered with extinct creatures and it's never led to irreversibly collapsed ecosystems
From a certain point of view...
But does that matter? For various reasons (we know now), bees are dwindling. I remember when it came into the public consciousness in the late 90s early 00s and I heard everything from unknown disease to aliens and it all caused a panic that the world would come to an end due to the loss of this important pollinator. The problem became better understood, the panic died, ecology survived, and we all moved on.
Let's be honest, an asteroid impact didn't irreversibly collapse ecosystems. Nor did an ice age. Of course, that depends on how you define "ecosystems." There are a couple of dinosaurs that might complain about my trivializing the loss of their ecosystem.... But life continued and the Earth replaced what it lost.
So it might be that we don't understand your goals with this. The sudden loss of 44% (Love the focus on 4's in this world, BTW) of even one specie would cause scientists to freak out and, about 48 hours later when everybody had a chance to watch the relevant Youtube videos, everyone under the age of 25 would freak out and, about a week later when everybody over the age of 25 who's busy trying to make a living and get their kids to soccer practice have had a chance to absorb what they assumed was their younger sibling's tendency to overreact, everybody would be freaking out. Kinda. It takes a lot to get a lot of people to freak out.
It's worth noting that it would take a lot to kill the Earth. So, if you want to compromise ecosystems you'd need to invoke something a bit more biblical, like 44% of all insects. Scientifically that probably wouldn't be enough, but it passes the believability test.
If, on the other hand, you're just looking for a trigger for your story (as in you just need people to freak out), then you're good to go.

Note there are a LOT more insects than humans on the planet. Even if we go by mass. I have seen the number 70x as much total mass in comparison to humans. This would have the most devastating effect on areas with high insect populations (say, a rainforest), as their predators would find themselves with a lack of food (unless they scavenge). That said, with the short time between generations, and the massive amount of eggs most insects lay, they should recover soon because of a lack of competition for resources.

Larger animals aren’t necessarily interested in eating crickets when they are dead. A lot of sight hunters and all sound hunters will need them to be moving. It might primarily be other crickets eating the corpses. That’s not a particularly healthy lifestyle, but it’s also something that crickets are pretty used to. Maybe the species that feed on the corpses recover more quickly than the ones that don’t, causing further problems?
I think you could probably find an angle to achieve the outcome you’re looking for, but you’re right to think that it’s not a guaranteed result. Maybe throw in other factors to push it towards a crisis. Like, if it was early winter in the Northern Hemisphere, and it was a particularly tough winter, it would take the insects and their predators longer to recover… and your entomologists might not fully notice the impact until spring.
